# Using plus equal operation using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, operators

In pandas, for series or DFs, is it possible to use `+=` operation, would it work? When I'm trying it it sometimes work and sometimes it does not I guess. I'm basically using `.loc` to access a part and update just that part. So I want to add a specific array or value to that `.loc` part, so using `+=` is allowed or not? Or are there any better alternatives to do the operation I'm trying to achieve.

edit, example:

`df.loc[...] += 2`

`df.loc[...] = df.loc[...] + 2`

Both works? or the first usage is not working in this context?

Comment: Please expand your post with examples that work and don't work

Comment: just did, thanks for the notice.

Comment: Depending on what you are indexing by, the result of `.loc[]` can be a single cell or a slice of a dataframe... We'll still need a bit more context